# Displaying different posts Via wp_list_categories()

Tags: posts, categories

I believe this problem to be quite simple but can't seem to get my head around how to solve it.

So I'm pulling in all the category with posts in using `wp_list_categories();`

My problem is when I click through it pulls in the correct posts but, I want it to pull in the correct posts and still have wp_list_categories links at the top so someone can switch between the posts.

So really all that needs to change is that when you click a category link the relevant posts get pulled looking the same as there displayed now.

I know this is going to involve conditions and maybe some new queries written - I want to try and do this in the most robust way possible.

[Link to the page](http://www.integrabuildings.co.uk/index.php/case-studies/)

code at the moment generating this page.

```
<?php
/*
 *  * Template Name: Case Studies
 */
?>
<?php global $up_options, $post, $paged, $wp_query; ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="bodywrapper">
        <?php $args = array(
            'title_li'           => __( '' ),
        ); ?>
        <div class="category-list"><?php wp_list_categories($args); ?></div>
    <div style="height: 25px"></div>

    <div id="content"> 
        <h1>Case Studies</h1>

     <?php
    $start = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
      $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5&post_type=post'.'&paged='.$paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                    ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                            <?php }?>
                        </a>
                        <h1 class="post-title"><a href="<?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lj_file_url', true) ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <div class="post-entry">
<a href="<?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lj_file_url', true) ?>" title="Download pdf <?php the_title(); ?>"> <img src="http://www.integra-av.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/pdflogo.png" alt="" class="alignleft"/></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <div class="clear">
                    <?php wpld_pagenavi(); ?>
                </div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 35px;"><span style="color: #2788e4;">Secure Solutions</span></span></p>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display). You'll need to create a `category.php` template file, since the category archive index is what gets displayed when clicking a category link in the `wp_list_categories()` output.

Comment: So it automatically displays a file named that - if thats correct then this is fairly simple for me to construct.